# Equivalent system call to vm_copy on linux

Tags: linux, macos, memory, copy-on-write

Is there a way to create a copy-on-write doublemapping of a region of virtual memory in linux similar to how vm_copy[[1]](http://web.mit.edu/darwin/src/modules/xnu/osfmk/man/vm_copy.html)[[2]](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MemoryAlloc.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001881-106546) works, which is available on OSes such as Hurd and OSX?

Specifically, *not with fork.*

Answer (score 0):

### OS X: vm_copy

It *does* exist.

The `OS X` variant of `vm_copy` does not touch any real memory, rather, it modifies the virtual memory map then tells the destination address range that it's a copy-on-write version of the source address range.

The small amount of info available on the subject can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/AboutMemory.html).